# Finding zeros and replacing them with another number in a matrix file by awk

Tags: shell, math, matrix, awk

I have a matrix where I want to replace every 0 with 0.1 and depending on how many zeros are replaced the max score in that line will be deducted by number of 0.1s added such that the below matrix will go from,

No line will contain only zeroes, since this is a probability matrix where each line adds up to1. If a highest number occurs more than once (0.5 in this case), then anyone can be changed,and the first line will always be the only one with letters in it,

```
>ACTTT  ASB  0.098
0   0      1    0   
0.75   0   0.25    0   
0   0      0    1   
0   1      0    0   
1   0      0    0   
1   0      0    0   
0   1      0    0   
0   1      0    0
```

to

```
>ACTTT  ASB  0.098
0.1   0.1      0.7    0.1   
0.55   0.1   0.25    0.1   
0.1  0.1      0.1    0.7   
0.1   0.7      0.1    0.1   
0.7   0.1      0.1    0.1  
0.7   0.1      0.1    0.1   
0.1   0.7      0.1    0.1   
0.1   0.7      0.1    0.1
```

I tried to use something like this in a loop from previous answers in here:

```
   while read line ; do echo $line | awk 'NR>1{print gsub(/(^|[[:space:]])0([[:space:]]|$)/,"&")}'; echo $line | awk '{max=$2;for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)if($i>max)max=$i}END{print max}'; done < matrix_file
```

Comment: What happens to a line containing only zeroes? What if the highest number occurs more than once? Does the size of the matrix change? Is the first line the only one with letters in it?

Comment: I think your math doesn't add up:  0.1 + 0.1 + 0.97 + 0.1 > 1.  Perhaps you meant 0.01?

Comment: Sorry my bad edited it :)

Comment: **Learn** from the answers and comments to your previous questions. Re-read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice until you understand it. Also to learn awk read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: I will thanks Ed Morton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v eps=0.01 'function maxIx() {mI=1;
                                     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                                         if($mI<$i)mI=i; 
                                     return mI} 
               NR>1{mX=maxIx(); 
                    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                        if($i==0) {$i=eps;$mX-=eps}}1' file

>ACTTT  ASB  0.098
0.01 0.01 0.97 0.01
0.73 0.01 0.25 0.01
0.01 0.01 0.01 0.97
0.01 0.97 0.01 0.01
0.97 0.01 0.01 0.01
0.97 0.01 0.01 0.01
0.01 0.97 0.01 0.01
0.01 0.97 0.01 0.01
```

defined eps, as long as you have a sensible value it should work fine, but doesn't check for going below zero.

Comment: thanks a lot , just learned how to write a function in awk through this code.